# Do you know any academic adverbs other than "therefore", "hence", "so", and "thus"?

Tags: synonyms, adverbs

I am writing an essay and I look for an academic adverb or adverb phrase that can help me to connect these two sentences.

- We need air to be able to breathe and continue to our lives. *[adverb]*, we need to make an effort to reduce the air pollution.

But I do not want to use **therefore**, **hence**, **so**, and **thus** adverbs, because I think I have over-used them in my writing. Do we have any other substitutes?

It might be a simple question for native speakers, but as a non-native speaker, I always feel that I am confined by those bolded adverbs above, and I want to look for something more fresh or different (but still acceptable to academia).

Comment: Ergo, accordingly, thence....

Comment: @user66974 Thank you so much for your kind sharing. I think ergo and thence might be old words. Are they common?

Comment: They are formal terms.

Comment: Another choice: 
*Because* we need air to breathe and continue to our lives, [no adverb] we need to make an effort to reduce [no the] air pollution.

Comment: If this is an academic article, I have to say that the second clause does not follow from the first.  Breathing polluted air may reduce the length of lives to a greater or lesser degree, but is not usually fatal in the short or medium term.  But one way to avoid the connectives you mention is  this:-  "That is why we we need to... etc"

Comment: *an academic adverb or adverb phrase* I think you are looking for a **formal** adverb or adverb phrase. :)

Comment: nevertheless, moreover, heretofore, whatsoever, incontrovertibly, dypsomaniacally, antidisestablishmentarianismally.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some to pick from: accordingly, basically, clearly, consequently, effectively, indeed, inevitably, necessarily, particularly, specifically, subsequently, ultimately.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/391644)

Comment: @fev This provides **twelve** answers to the question. ('Do we have any other substitutes?') Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: answers without research are not answers. They should be comments.

Answer (score 0):

> We need air to be able to breathe and continue to our lives. ***On that account***, we need to make an effort to reduce the air pollution.

Instead of "on that account", you could also use:

> ***For this reason/As a result/Consequently***,...

You can find many other synonyms on [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/consequently.html).